# how to know position of the word that preg_match has found

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to find a special word, using **preg_match** in a string and echo 100 characters that comes after it.
 
For this, i need to know the **position of the word** that `preg_match()` has found.

Perhaps you will advise me to use `strpos()` for finding its position but the problem with `strpos()` is for instance when I have two words of "smart" and "art" in my string and "smart" came before "art", strpos finds "smart" while I wanted it to find "art". That's why I decided to use `preg_match()`.

the below code is the one I have written:

```
<?php pattern = "/\b' .$data[title]. '\b/i" ; 
      $article= $data['description'];     
      preg_match($pattern, $article, $matches);    echo '. $matches .' ;
?>
```

for example :

```
  <?php $pattern = "/\b' .art. '\b/i" ;   
        $article= "I didn’t think parents do not like that either…but son is so smart.who is studying art therapy";      
        preg_match($pattern, $article, $matches);        
        echo '. $art .' ;  
  ?>
```

Comment: Using the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag perhaps? [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to get the 100 characters directly:

```
 <?php 
   $pattern = "/\bart\b(.{100})/i";   
   $article= "I didn’t think parents do not like that either…but son is so smart.who is studying art therapy I didn’t think parents do not like that either…but son is so smart I didn’t think parents do not like that either…but son is so smart";      
  preg_match($pattern, $article, $matches);        
  print_r($matches);  
  echo 'Length: '+strlen($matches[1])
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => art therapy I didn’t think parents do not like that either…but son is so smart I didn’t think par
  [1] =>  therapy I didn’t think parents do not like that either…but son is so smart I didn’t think par
)
Length: 100
```